# How do I run multiple instances of a command and be able to cancel a certain instance in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I have a simple discord.py bot that pretty much just counts to whatever number a user wants. So far, the command looks like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def count(ctx, startNum, endNum):
  startNum = int(startNum)
  endNum = int(endNum)
  currentNum = startNum
  if startNum > endNum:
    await ctx.send("nice try, i'm not counting backwards")

  while currentNum < (endNum + 1) or startNum < endNum:
    await ctx.send(ctx.message.author.name + ": " + str(currentNum))
    currentNum += 1
  await ctx.send(ctx.message.author.mention + " I've finished counting to " + str(endNum))
```

Lets say you run `count 10`, it will display

```
username: 1
username: 2
username: 3
...
username: 10
```

I would like to create a command that pretty much allows a user to cancel *one specific counter* and not any others.

Preferably, each counter would display a seperate counter ID, which you can then cancel using a command like `cancel ID`. It would sort of look like:

```
> count 1 50
CounterID: 1
CounterID: 2
CounterID: 3
> cancel CounterID
CounterID has been cancelled
```

How could this be done?

Comment: You have infinite loop, because `startNum < endNum` is `True` all time. Or is it right for you?

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop, you could add a `wait_for` event with a timeout of 1 second:

```py
import asyncio # for the exception

@bot.command()
async def count(...):
    # code

    # make sure the person cancelling the timer is the original requester
    # and they are cancelling it from the same channel
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and \
               msg.content.lower().startswith("cancel")

    while currentNum < endNum:
        try:
            msg = await bot.wait_for(message, check=check, timeout=1)
            await ctx.send("Your counter has been cancelled!")
            break # break the loop if they send a message starting with "cancel"
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send(ctx.author.name + ": " + str(currentNum))
            currentNum += 1
```

Though that example won't allow for specific counters to be cancelled (apart from a user's own counter). If you had some database (such as json, sqlite, mongodb etc.), you could perhaps store current counter IDs for each user.

---

**References:**

- [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)
- [`asyncio.TimeoutError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.TimeoutError)